# How do I turn a 1x1 alias into a scalar?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to turn counts into probabilities:

```
total = foreach (group A all) generate SUM(A.count);
A = foreach A generate A.count / total as probability;
```

This does not work because `total` is an alias, not a scalar:

> Invalid scalar projection: total : A column needs to be projected from
>   a relation for it to be used as a scalar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the alias `total` just has one field (the sum) you still have to reference that field.

This should work:

```
total = foreach (group A all) generate SUM(A.count) as total;
A = foreach A generate A.count / total.total as probability;
```

Comment: Will it work without casting total.total to int/long?

Comment: @Ruslan I'm pretty sure it will.  The output of `SUM` should default to a long so you don't have to do `SUM(A.count) AS total:long ;`.

Comment: Ok. BTW, the syntax for casting doesn't work in Pig anyway: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2315

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
total = foreach (group A all) generate SUM(A.count) as total_sum;
A = foreach A generate count / (int)total.total_sum as probability;
```

Here http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#cast
Search for "Casting Relations to Scalars"